# An efficient trie implementation for .net

Tags: .net, collections, trie, in-memory

I am looking for a trie implementation for .net.

I am planning to use it as the index structure for my in-memory object pool. It need not be thread safe (as only one thread will be updating it) but should be able to cope with at least 20 million items gracefully and with constant performance.

The ones I found on the net seems to be sample code or toy projects. So, I am really looking for a production quality implementation. Commercial libraries are also OK, if available.

PS:I selected tries as it seems hash table implementations that I have seen use too much memory and tend to cause memory fragmentations as they are based on arrays. Any such container with O(1) lookup characteristics and benign memory usage characteristics for large number of items could also be OK.

Thank you,

Comment: 20 million items?  The memory usage of a trie in this case is almost guaranteed to be larger than a dictionary/hashtable - possibly by several orders of magnitude...  Also do you actually need an in-memory pool of objects?  .Net's own memory management is pretty rock-solid.

Comment: What standard data structures did you try, and did fit your need? (explain why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal opinion attempting to second-guess .Net's own memory management is not a practise I'd recommend.  You simply can't exert the level of control over memory allocation that you can in a native scenario, but equally you shouldn't need to.  I was obsessed by a desire to do this when I first moved from C++ (where I would regularly work with my own heaps and write memory-localisation routines etc), but it swiftly became apparent that I just didn't need to, nor *could* I.

For example, you could have an array of `MyPooledObject` at the bottom of your trie, but, if that is a reference type, then you've just got an array of references, where the actual memory for each is somewhere else - that you can't control (unless you adapt your own host for the runtime).

That leaves using a value-type instead - but these are simply not suitable for use in a pooled scenario, because custom value types should be immutable (I can say that safely without justifying it - just google 'immutable' and 'struct' targetting site:stackoverflow.com to see more) and therefore no good to be treated as reusable objects.

If you need an indexed collection of objects in .Net where each is recognisable with a hash-capable key, then use a Dictionary.

If you have too many objects to fit in memory then either:

1) Get more memory

2) Use a database and cache local segments of it

Or both: You could consider looking at [AppFabric and its cache features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731.aspx), that way you can build a farm of machines dedicated to running in-memory caches of millions of objects.  The cost of the hardware will probably be less than the cost of developing your own memory management solution for .Net :)

Comment: I actually tried all hash table implementations in .net framework and also C5 library. The issue with hash tables is that they are based on arrays. Once their array buffers are filled up, they try to reallocate the whole structure at double capacity. So if there is a lot of adds going on the system, it results in memory fragmentation and out of memory errors as the contiguous memory locations are quickly depleted. A hash table implementation that does not work that way would be very useful but could not find that one either.

Comment: An array of references is roughly as large as the size of a pointer array would be.  In your case 20 mill = around 80Mb or 160Mb in 64-bit land.  Why not just create the hashtable or dictionary with a large initial capacity?

Comment: Thanks Zoltan, and sorry for late reply. I must have missed that I did not reply to your suggestions. It is indeed how I ended up doing i.e. pre-allocate a large chunk close to my final size and let it play around using a standard dictionary. I also played with cutting the dictionary key to smaller portions and keeping a hierarchy of dictionaries. That also works but keeping track of sub-sub dictionaries is complex and does not provide much advantage if I know the ballpark figure of the maximum size. So, I went with the simple approach in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library: [TrieNet](https://github.com/gmamaladze/trienet)

```
using Gma.DataStructures.StringSearch;

...

var trie = new SuffixTrie<int>(3);

trie.Add("hello", 1);
trie.Add("world", 2);
trie.Add("hell", 3);

var result = trie.Retrieve("hel");
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: 1. This is exactly the expected answer to the question. So why not? 2. I am the author of this broadly used library and there are enough examples and documentation in the repository.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259. You should include an example in the answer.